# Geting a view based on pk using url pattern

Tags: python, html, django

Hay. I have a little trouble getting URL with the passed argument (pk). I get error in which I get post_edit that is to do with another app of the website so as a pattern it tried to use:

**NoReverseMatch at /questions/question/5/
Reverse for 'post_edit' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/post/(?P[0-9]+)/edit/$']**

Why doesn't it pass pk in questions_list.html in a for loop?

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.questionMain_view, name='questionMain_view'),
    path('postQ/', views.postQ_view, name='postQ_view'),
    path('all/', views.displayQ_view, name='displayQ_view'),
    path('question/<int:pk>/', views.question_detail_view, name='question_detail_view'),
]
```

questions_list.html

```html
{% extends 'questions_page/base_questions.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %} {% translate 'Questions Main' %} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{% translate 'Questions display' %}</h1>
    <br>

    {% for question in questions %}
    <div>
        <div class="date">
            {{ question.published_date }}
        </div>
        <h1><a href="{% url 'question_detail_view' question.pk %}">{{ question.title }}</a></h1>
        <p>{{ question.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

questions_detail.html

```html
{% extends 'questions_page/base_questions.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %} {% translate 'Questions detail' %} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{% translate 'Questions detail' %}</h1>
    <br>

    <div>
        {% if question.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ question.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <!-- <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> -->
        {% endif %}
        <h1>{{ question.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ question.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

viws.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import ImageForm, QuestionForm
from .models import Image, Question

# Create your views here.
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='Premium').count() > 0)
@login_required
def questionMain_view(request):
    return render(request, 'questions_page/questions_main.html')

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='Premium').count() > 0)
@login_required
def postQ_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        questionForm = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.user)
        img_form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if questionForm.is_valid() and img_form.is_valid():
            question_obj = questionForm.save(commit=False)
            question_obj.user = request.user
            question_obj.save()
            for img in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
                Image.objects.create(image=img, question=question_obj)
            return redirect('postQ_view')

    questionForm = QuestionForm()
    img_form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    return render(request, 'questions_page/postQ.html', {"questionForm":questionForm, "img_form": img_form})

def displayQ_view(request):

    questions = Question.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, 'questions_page/questions_list.html', {'questions' : questions})

def question_detail_view(request, pk):

    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'questions_page/question_detail.html', {'question': question})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the cause of the error
in your `questions_detail.html` template you have this code

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <!-- <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> -->
% endif %}
```

change it to

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

        {% comment %}<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> {% endcomment %}
    {% endif %}
```

`<!---->` tags do not comment out django code rather comments out  only html

but we use `{% comment %} {% endcomment %}` to comment out django code in the html template

for more information on how to comment in django framework visit [official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-comment)